# Access Tomcat manager from another machine from another network

Tags: java, tomcat, server, vps

I'm getting a 403 trying to even access logging page of tomcat manager.

Is it even possible? 
If not how can I use tomcat on my virtual private server?

Comment: Its a simple webpage, you can access it by ip, port and context path (application name). Http 403 means the access to the url has been denied, so you need to find out, why it got blocked.

Comment: The problem is that it can be access only from localhost(/manager/html) and I need to change that setting but can't find anywhere how.